# How to simplify this complex expression?

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x, y) = x^2 - xy$.  Determine a simplified expression for $f(x, x-y)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute $y$ with $x-y$ in the expression  which gives

$f(x,x-y)=x^2-x(x-y)=xy$